# less and bootstrap not working together?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

new to less and trying to use less instead of css for faster loading.  When I link the bootstrap.css file, everything works fine but when I try to get less to work, it doesn't.  Not sure what I'm missing, I included the js file and the .less bootstrap file:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
  <script src="bower_components/less/dist/less.js"></script>
```

Comment: See you browser console for whatever errors it complains. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, just "not working" is useless (At least specify what results you're expecting to get, and what you actually get instead).

Comment: can you provide fiddle